# Duda sobre Constructores y uso de getters and Setters

Tags: java

estoy practicando con un programa para leer datos de un Pseudo sensor de Velocidad y presión usando getters Y setter. Como no existe el sensor se ha asignado los valores que el usuario ingrese via lector desde el metodo main.

El ejercicio pide explicitamente Que la clase debe tener dos constructores y no se como llegar a eso. De momento tengo este codígo que Funciona Bastante bien. Pero no cumple con la petición de tener dos constructores, o al menos no lo puedo ver.

```
package sensores;

public class Auto {
     private double angularSpeed;
     private double pres;
     private String name;

        public Auto()
        {

        }


        public double getSpeed()
        {
            return angularSpeed;
        }

        public void setSpeed(double s)


{
        angularSpeed = s;
    }

    public double getPres()
    {
        return pres;
    }

    public void setPres(double p)
    {
        pres = p;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
     public void setName(String n){
         name = n;
     }
```

}

Tengo entendido que podría crear un segundo constructor tal que así.

```
public Auto(double speed, double pres){
   this.pres = pres;
   this.speed = speed;
}
```

Esto serviria para asignar los setters, pero los getters quedan fuera.. se puede hacer esto? y de ser el caso, como implemento los getters?

Comment: Es exactamente como dices, y los getters serian los que tienes ya hechos.

Comment: Una pregunta sobre Buneas practicas, no resulta redundante usar 2 constructores? o es solo mi idea?

Comment: Es totalmente correcto tener varios constructores. Echale un ojo a esto http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=506:clases-con-dos-o-mas-constructores-en-java-sobrecarga-de-constructores-o-metodos-ejemplo-cu00640b&catid=68&Itemid=188

Comment: A tener varios constructores, se le llama "sobrecarga" (sobrecarga de constructor en este caso, pero también se puede hacer con métodos), y no es para nada malo, muchas clases propias de java tiene sobrecargados sus métodos. Por complementar lo que te ha pasado el compañero. Tiro de wiki: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobrecarga_(inform%C3%A1tica)

Answer (score 6):

Al igual que los métodos, los constructores también se pueden *sobrecargar* ([ver especificación del lenguaje Java, apartado 8.8.8: *Constructor Overloading*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.8)),  es decir, que una clase puede tener **varios constructores**.

Tener **varios** constructores (porque podemos tener más de dos si es necesario), no es una mala práctica si su uso está justificado. Esto es útil si queremos tener una clase con constructores que hagan diferentes tareas.

Así, podemos crear instancias de la clase:

- llamando el constructor por defecto: `new Clase();` en cuyo caso la misma adquirirá los valores que hayan sido indicados por defecto ... o valores nulos en caso de no tener valores por defecto.
- llamando otro constructor con sus parámetros `new Clase(param 1, param 2, param ...);`, en cuyo caso se creará con los parámetros especificados.

He aquí un ejemplo. En comentarios del código se explica lo esencial:

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/PZPP8171)

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

       /*Creando el objeto de esta forma
        * llamará al constructor por defecto
        * y si hay valores por defecto los adquiere
        * si no hay valores establece todo a null, 0.0, etc.
        */

      Auto myAuto1 = new Auto();
       System.out.println("Valor de AngularSpeed: "+myAuto1.getAngularSpeed());
       System.out.println("Valor de Pre: "+myAuto1.getPres());
       System.out.println("Valor de Name: "+myAuto1.getName());

       /*Creando el objeto de esta forma
        * llamará al constructor con parámetros*/
       Auto myAuto2 = new Auto(10.2, 2.2, "Nombre Auto 2");
       System.out.println("Valor de AngularSpeed: "+myAuto2.getAngularSpeed());
       System.out.println("Valor de Pre: "+myAuto2.getPres());
       System.out.println("Valor de Name: "+myAuto2.getName());

    }
}



class Auto
{

     private double dblAngularSpeed;
     private double dblPres;
     private String strName;

   Auto()
   {
       //Constructor por defecto... los valores no son obligatorios

       dblAngularSpeed = 0.0;
       dblPres = 0.0;
       strName = "Nuevo";

   }
   Auto(double dblAngularSpeed1, double dblPres1, String strName1)
   {
       //Constructor con parámetros
       dblAngularSpeed = dblAngularSpeed1;
       dblPres = dblPres1;
       strName = strName1;
   }
   //Getters y Setters
   public double getAngularSpeed() {
       return dblAngularSpeed;
   }
   public void setAngularSpeed(double dblAngularSpeed) {
       this.dblAngularSpeed = dblAngularSpeed;
   }
   public double getPres() {
       return dblPres;
   }
   public void setPres(double dblPres) {
       this.dblPres = dblPres;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return strName;
   }
   public void setName(String strName) {
       this.strName = strName;
   }
}
```

#### `Resultado`:

```
Valor de AngularSpeed: 0.0
Valor de Pre: 0.0
Valor de Name: Nuevo

Valor de AngularSpeed: 10.2
Valor de Pre: 2.2
Valor de Name: Nombre Auto 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes crear un constructor que reciba parámetros y otro que no reciba parámetros y este haga una llamada al constructor con parámetros para asignar un valor por defecto

```
public Auto(double angularSpeed,double press,String name){
     this.angularSpeed = angularSpeed;
     this.press = press;
     this.name = name;
}

public Auto() {
     Auto(2.5,3.4,"por defecto");
}
```

Por ejemplo de esta forma cuando alguien llama al constructor sin parámetros se le asigna unos valores por defectos a los atributos