# Como llamar de un contructor a otro Constructor en Java

Tags: java, constructor

Tengo estos 3 constructores en una clase de java, como seria la forma correcta de hacer que uno llame al otro, es decir llamar al por defecto, que este llame al siguiente con menos parámetros y este ultimo al que tiene todos los parametros
ejemplo:

```
    public Correo(String from, String to, String asunto, String texto) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.asunto = asunto;
        this.texto = texto;
        this.leido = false;
        this.fecha.getDate();
    }


  public Correo() {  }

  public Correo(String from) {
        this.from = from;
}
```

Comment: Yo preguntaría cuál es el sentido de hacer lo que pretendes. ¿Tienes claro **[para qué una Clase se declara con diferentes constructores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86975/29967)**? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo práctico sobre un **escenario real** dónde vayas a usar  tu Clase de esa forma? Quizá imaginando un escenario en el que algo así tuviese sentido te darías cuenta de que intentar hacer eso no es una buena idea.

Comment: estoy haciendo un apiRest com springboot, y para hacer pruebas uso postman y hasta donde entendi postman recibe solo constructores por defecto, pero yo necesito crear objetos con parametros que se les pasa al constructor, pero como postman solo recibe sin parametros debo llamar de ese por defecto al que tiene parametro... estoy comenzando a utilizar spring y postman asi que no se si llego a ser del todo claro

Comment: No puedes llamar a un constructor sin parámetros y luego rellenar las propiedades del objeto a través de métodos setter? lo de llamar de un constructor a otro... además, si no le mandas parámetros al constructor, ¿cómo vas a llamar al constructor con parámetros desde el que no recibe nada?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes llamar un contructor desde otro constructor usando el [keyword `this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html). La única restricción en su uso es que debe ser la primera sentencia en el constructor.

Ejemplo:

```
public Correo(String from, String to, String asunto, String texto) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.asunto = asunto;
    this.texto = texto;
    this.leido = false;
}

public Correo() {
    this("from"); // asignas los valores por defecto deseado
}

public Correo(String from) {
    this(from, "tu", "asunto", "texto"); // asignas los valores por defecto deseado
}
```

Comment: @A. Cedano: Si fuera tal como lo describes, en verdad sería pésimo. Pero no es así. Si el constructor encadena 3 veces, no está creando 3 objetos. Solo crea 1. Es solo que al crear el objeto, el código de 3 constructores participan en la inicialización. Esta técnica es perfectamente válida en muchas situaciones para definir valores por defecto durante la creación de un objeto sin repetir demasiado código. Si no fuera como lo describo, entonces esta documentación oficial tendría serios problemas en el ejemplo que presenta: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html.

Comment: Entendido, yo enfoqué el problema pensando en que el OP construiría cada vez nuevas instancias del objeto. Ahora entiendo mejor, viendo el ejemplo del enlace de la clase `Rectangulo`. Borro comentario anterior y gracias por la explicación.