# ¿Como Funciona La Herencia Entre Clases?

Tags: java

No puedo lograr entender algo simple, explico continuación:

Tengo la clase **MainActivity.java**(La principal) y luego creo otra clase de nombre  **Funcion.java** entonces
en la clase **Funcion** 
todo el contenido (Esta todo vacio)

```
public class Funcion {
}
```

en la clase **MainActivity** agrego el siguiente codigo:

```
 Funcion f = new Funcion(); //Creo un objeto de la clase funcion
```

todo anda bien, pero ahora en la clase **Funcion** agrego una función que pide un parametro con el nombre de la clase:

```
public class Funcion {

public  Funcion(String nombre)
{
    String name = nombre;
}
}
```

Ahora en la clase **MainActivity** agrego lo siguiente:

```
 Funcion f = new Funcion();
```

Me da un error y me dice que debo pasar un String como parametro entonces debo hacerlo asi

```
 Funcion f = new Funcion("Nombre");
```

No entiendo la utilidad de realizar esta acción y porque es tan utilizadas en adaptadores o base de datos. 
**¿No se para que sirve?**

Comment: Podriamos cambiar el titulo? porque esto no tiene nada pero nada que ver con herencia

Comment: La cuestión va de **constructores**. [Te dejo este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86975/29967), porque creo que puede arrojar un poco más de luz sobre esta situación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que todo es saber que lo estas haciendo no es herencia, lo segundo es que tu constructor en la clase `Funcion`  lo creaste para pedir un String como parámetro, puedes crear múltiples constructores en tu clase así:

```
public class Funcion {

    private String nombre;

    public  Funcion(String nombre) //Constructor con paramentro
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public  Funcion(){ //Constructor sin paramentro
        this.nombre = "";
    }

    public String getNombre(){ //Metodo selector
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){ //Metodo modificador
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

En tu `MainActivity` puedes crear una instancia de `Funcion` de dos maneras en este caso

```
//Primera forma
Funcion funcion1 = new Funcion("Android");
funcion1.getText(); //Android

//Segunda forma
Funcion funcion2 = new Funcion();
funcion2.setNombre("Android")
funcion2.getNombre(); //Android
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public  Funcion(String nombre)
```

no es una función<sup>1</sup>, es un **constructor**.

Un constructor se usa para la creación de una instancia de la clase (que es lo que haces con `new Funcion("Hola")`.

En el primer ejemplo

```
 public class Funcion {
 }
```

como no has definido ningún constructor, Java añade el **constructor implícito**, que es un constructor sin parámetros. Eso es lo que estás invocando al hacer `new Funcion()`. Cuando añades tu propio constructor, Java deja de añadir el constructor implícito por lo que el código que lo usa deja de compilar.

---

<sup>1</sup>En Java se habla más de métodos que de funciones.

Answer (score 0):

la mayoria de los constructores de las clases pasan parametros para procesar informacion, en android se utiliza mas para pasar contextos, pero tu en la clase deberias crear dos constructores, el uno recibe parametros y otro vacio, todo depende de lo que vaya a hacer tu clase, en los adaptadores se utiliza para recibir listas y poblar un listview o algun componente.

```
public class Funcion {
    public  Funcion()
    {
    }

    public  Funcion(String nombre)
    {
      String name = nombre;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo que tu explicas no es herencia, es mas instancias de objetos(clases). Herencia es cuando utilizas "exteds" y el nombre de la clase de la cual heredas por ejemplo seria: Class MainActivity exteds Funcion{  } en la cual todos los metodos public que tenga en la clase Funcion voy a poder utilizar en el MainActivity

Comment: tienes razón, mi error el no haber fijado que era constructor y no clase.

Answer (score 0):

La utilidad de "hacer eso" radica en la capacidad de construcción de las clases, por eso se llama constructor, por que "construye a la clase" y no solo eso, al crear un objeto puedes mover su contenido dentro del código, trayendo la informacion que lo acompaña, por eso se dice que "instancias", mira lo siguiente...

```
    public class Contact
{
private String name;
private String address;
public Contact(String name,String address)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

Esta clase fácilmente podría representar a una entidad de alguna base de datos x, y como abrir y cerrar conexiones a una base de datos tiene su coste a nivel computacional, te puede resultar mas optimo bajar los datos a un tipo de estructura como esta, para trabajar sobre ellos.